# String with suffix fails parsing

Tags: c#, string, parsing, decimal

When ever one passes string with suffix parsing to `decimal` fails.

```
decimal testValue;
decimal.TryParse("5M", NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out testValue)
```

Following parse will return `false`.

Why does `TryParse` fail when you pass in a string with a suffix?

Comment: Why should it succeed? What is this `M` supposed to mean? It doesn't mean anything eg for RAM or disk sizes. In some domains, this may mean million. Or not.

Comment: I don't see much point in the suffix being there for parsing when you already know which type you want it to be. The point of the m suffix in C# code itself is to choose the `decimal` type when you would normally get another type.

Comment: What does `5M` actually mean in this example? Is it 5 or 5000000 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Decimal.TryParse` [does not support it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

> Depending on the value of style, the s parameter may include the following elements:
>
> [ws][$][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][e[sign]digits][ws]
>
> Elements in square brackets ([ and ]) are optional. The following table describes each element.
>
> `ws`: Optional white space. White space can appear at the beginning of s if style includes the NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite flag. It can appear at the end of s if style includes the NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite flag.
>
> `$`: A culture-specific currency symbol. Its position in the string is defined by the NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern or NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern properties of the NumberFormatInfo object returned by the IFormatProvider.GetFormat method of the provider parameter. The currency symbol can appear in s if style includes the NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol flag.
>
> `sign`: An optional sign.
>
> `digits`: A sequence of digits ranging from 0 to 9.
>
> `.`: A culture-specific decimal point symbol.
>
> `fractional-digits`: A sequence of digits ranging from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is *no way* to parse your string without removing `M` part. And none of [`NumberStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) have such a functionality.

I *can* suggest to `Replace` your `M` with empty string but that would be only solve for your case, it won't be a general solution.

```
decimal testValue;
decimal.TryParse("5M".Replace("M", ""), NumberStyles.Number, 
                                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out testValue);
```

A *real-type-suffix* specifies number types. It teaches to C# compiler what a numeric literal type considered as. In a string, it means *nothing*. It is just an another character.

Comment: @Carl you should post a *separate* question asking what you want - how to parse `5M` so that it means (I assume) 5 Million. Check for duplicate questions first though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually I'm guessing the OP has that there because  `M` is the suffix for decimal.

Comment: @juharr proves my point  - the same suffix will mean different things for different *domains*. A framework function can't be expected to handle this. That's the job of domain-specific libraries, eg math libraries